How to work with Enum correclty in SQLAlchemy
What should I do in order to make SQLAlchemy use the value of an Enum instead the name?
I have the following scenario:
class ReportStatus(enum.Enum):
  PENDING = 'pending'
  PROCESSING = 'processing'
  DONE = 'done'
  ERROR = 'error'

class Report(Base):
    id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, index=True)
    status = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Enum(ReportStatus), default=ReportStatus.PENDING)

But whenever I try to query the data from the database I receive the following message:
"'done' is not among the defined enum values. Enum name: reportstatus. Possible values: PENDING, PROCESSING, DONE, ERROR"


What happens if you query for "DONE" instead of "done"?

Declaring an ENUM (SQL) column like you do, is valid. However it will store the name of the member and not its value.
Values stored in your DB :



id
status




1
PENDING


2
DONE



For your enum : Name = UPPERCASE, values = lowercase.
The error looks like it's coming from an update/insert: you are trying to store "done" (enum value) instead of "DONE" (enum name). If this is the case, consider create/update using directly enum members :
status_as_string = "done"
report = Report()
report.status = ReportStatus(status_as_string)
# persist in DB

If this is what you want, I'd recommend using enum members everywhere you can and convert strings that represent values of the enum early before using them with SQLAlchemy.
If you want to store enum values instead, and be able to assign "done" to Report.status. Use values_callable in your column declaration :
status =  Column(Enum(ReportStatus, values_callable=lambda obj: [e.value for e in obj])

Be aware that, if you already have names (UPPERCASE) stored in your DB, adding values_callable will break stuff and you'll need to migrate (lower()) existing values in the DB.
My first snippet will still be valid and you will still be able to use enum members "everywhere" (SQLAlchemy will do the casting for you).
SIDE NOTE:
I faced the same issues and also had issues with "select" and comparisons in general ("done" != "DONE") leading to an excessive use of .value.
Using str type as a mixin in enums declaration for my columns. If you're working with python3.11+ use StrEnum, like so:
class NewReportStatus(str, enum.Enum):
  PENDING = 'pending'
  PROCESSING = 'processing'
  DONE = 'done'
  ERROR = 'error'

ReportStatus.DONE == "done"  # False, need to use .value
NewReportStatus.DONE == "done" # True

Makes the code more readable, IMO.
